How to calculate a rank measure correctly in Power BI based on filtered conditions?
Scenario:
I have a Power BI model with a table (table1) that has the following columns:
date, asset_class, broker, trade_type, traded_usd
Setup:
I have applied a filter on asset_class and selected FX.
I also have slicers for date and broker.
I created a table visual where:
trade_type is the first column,
traded_usd is the second column, and
I want a measure Traded_USD_Rank that ranks brokers based on traded_usd within each trade_type.
Objective:
If one trade_type (e.g., Algo) has 10 brokers, when I select a specific broker in the slicer, I should get its rank within that trade_type based on the traded_usd column.
Issue:
I tried writing a measure for ranking (including formulas from ChatGPT), but the output is inconsistent in a few cases:

Sometimes, all rows show 1 as the rank.
Occasionally, the top two brokers both have rank 1, even when their traded_usd values are different.
After that, the ranks skip numbers (e.g., the next rank is 5, followed by 32, instead of going serially).

Example Table Visual:
For a selected Broker A, I want to see this result. There are two more brokers with more than 50000 traded_usd in Algo and there are one more Broker with more than 40000 traded_usd in Swap.



Trade Type
traded_usd
traded_usd_rank




Algo
50000
3


Swap
40000
2



Question:
How can I write a measure that ranks brokers serially (without skipping numbers) based on traded_usd within each trade_type?
Why are ranks showing incorrectly in cases where traded_usd differs but the rank remains the same?
Would appreciate any help or better DAX formula suggestions to resolve this!
trade_usd_rank = VAR selecteddaterange = VALUES(table1[date])
RETURN RANKX(
FILTER(
ALL(table1[broker]),
COUNTROWS(
INTERSECT(VALUES(table1[date]), selecteddaterange)
) > 0
), CALCULATE(SUM(table1[traded_usd])),
,
DESC,
SKIP
)

